# Sister turns her younger brother to a pig

Tags: story-identification, movie

Back in the late 90s or early 00's I saw this movie about a teen girl, 
a  sister that turns her small brother to a pig with some magic trick or some curse.  I think they go to a witch but no helps a lot o she tells them they have to go somewhere to break the curse. For some reason I believe they have to go to Mexico to undo the curse.   I think the cast was all white.

Comment: Animated or not?

Comment: It is live action,  someone already answerd tho.  But thanks!

Comment: " I think they go to a witch but no helps a lot o she tells them they have to go somewhere to break the curse." I can't determine what you intended for this sentence to say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [*My Brother the Pig*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Brother_the_Pig) (1999)

> A boy named George is magically transformed into a pig. In a dangerous and crazy adventure, the boy, his sister, Kathy, his best friend Freud, and their housekeeper Matilda leave for Mexico to try to undo the witchcraft before their parents return from their Paris trip.

Comment: Yes,  thanks I can finally see the ending of this movie

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Yeah, the parents finding out is the worst thing that could possibly happen.  “… so I won’t be grounded … for the rest of my natural life!”  (There’s a line in there about being on tomorrow’s menu; I guess that’s a secondary concern.)    :-)    ⁠